# Android Media Stream Error? java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider :http://

Tags: android, media-player, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I followed [this](https://github.com/Old-Geek/Radio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/oucho/radio/MainActivity.java) to Play Stream Radio In android

Here Its working Fine But Player Loading Bit Slow after clicking I need to wait for 30+ seconds time

But I am getting This error In console

```
MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException happend : 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://www.example.com:8000/live.ogg
at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1074)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:927)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:854)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1087)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1061)
at org.oucho.radio.Player.playLaunch(Player.java:237)
at org.oucho.radio.Playlist.onPostExecute(Playlist.java:98)
at org.oucho.radio.Playlist.onPostExecute(Playlist.java:35)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

In the Link You can see all files like [player](https://github.com/Old-Geek/Radio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/oucho/radio/Player.java) etc

Due to this error My stream Is slow. Please any one help me on this type

Here this error is not with **`.ogg`** file I tried with **`.mp3`** and Just **`/live`**

```
http://www.example.com:8000/beet.ogg
http://www.example.com:8000/mouthorgan.mp3
http://www.example.com:8000/live
```

The Audio is playing but after this error It is taking some 30 seconds time Some times it is taking too long ....When I plays Its showing this error and then its connecting to server.. and playing

please help me to fix this

Comment: Just change HTTP to HTTPS. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
>   http://www.example.com:8000/live.ogg

Because its trying load as a file from device contentprovider based on the context and you are passing as a URL.

Seems your issue is in setting datasource to mediaplayer. As you are trying to play url or streaming which required to [setDataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)) method without context.

I was facing same issue while playing live streaming. and below code resolved my issue.

**PlayerScreen**

```
        public class PlayerScreen extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.player);
            startService(new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class));
            findViewById(R.id.btnChangeTrack).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            findViewById(R.id.btnStartMediaPlayer).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            findViewById(R.id.btnStopMediaPlayer).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglePauseResume);
            toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);
            /*
            * To get url which is passing from the previous activity listitem click.
            * If url which is pass from listitem click is not empty it will start player
            * */
            String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
                startMediaPlayer(url);

        }

        private ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener checkedChangeListener = new ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (!isChecked) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.PAUSE_MEDIA_PLAYER);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.RESUME_MEDIA_PLAYER);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            }
        };
        private View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent;
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btnChangeTrack:
                        intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.CHANGE_PLAYER_TRACK);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_TRACK_URL, "http://www.example.com:8000/live");
                        sendBroadcast(intent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnStartMediaPlayer:
                        startMediaPlayer("http://www.example.com:8000/beet.ogg");
//startMediaPlayer("http://108.163.197.114:8071/listen.pls");
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnStopMediaPlayer:
                        intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.STOP_MEDIA_PLAYER);
                        sendBroadcast(intent);
                        break;

                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            registerReceiver(receiverFromservice, new IntentFilter(MediaPlayerService.SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY));
        }

        private String currentPlayerStatus = "N/A";
        private BroadcastReceiver receiverFromservice = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (MediaPlayerService.SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                    /*
                    * To get current status of player
                    * */
                    currentPlayerStatus = intent.getStringExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_STATUS_KEY);
                    Log.e("Player Mode", "" + currentPlayerStatus);
                }
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            unregisterReceiver(receiverFromservice);
        }

        /**
         * TO start media player.It will send broadcast to Service & from service player will start
         *
         * @param url
         */
        public void startMediaPlayer(String url) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.PLAY_MEDIA_PLAYER);
            intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_TRACK_URL, url);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }
```

**MediaPlayerService**

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service {
    public static final String BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE = "com.mediaplayer.playerfunction";
    public static final String SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY = "com.mediaplayer.currentPlayerStatus";
    public static final String PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE = "playerfunction";
    public static final String PLAYER_TRACK_URL = "trackURL";
    public static final int PLAY_MEDIA_PLAYER = 1;
    public static final int PAUSE_MEDIA_PLAYER = 2;
    public static final int RESUME_MEDIA_PLAYER = 3;
    public static final int STOP_MEDIA_PLAYER = 4;
    public static final int CHANGE_PLAYER_TRACK = 5;
    public static final String PLAYER_STATUS_KEY = "PlayerCurrentStatus";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
        registerReceiver(playerReceiver, intentFilter);
        if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            sendPlayerStatus("playing");
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver playerReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                String trackURL = intent.hasExtra(PLAYER_TRACK_URL) ? intent.getStringExtra(PLAYER_TRACK_URL) : "";
                int function = intent.getIntExtra(PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, 0);
                switch (function) {
                    case CHANGE_PLAYER_TRACK:
                        changeTrack(trackURL);
                        break;
                    case STOP_MEDIA_PLAYER:
                        stopPlayer();
                        break;
                    case PLAY_MEDIA_PLAYER:
                        startMediaPlayer(trackURL);
                        break;
                    case PAUSE_MEDIA_PLAYER:
                        pausePlayer();
                        break;
                    case RESUME_MEDIA_PLAYER:
                        resumePlayer();
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    };
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    private void pausePlayer() {
        if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            sendPlayerStatus("pause");
        }
    }

    private void resumePlayer() {
        if (mPlayer != null && !mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.start();
            sendPlayerStatus("playing");
        }
    }

    private void changeTrack(String url) {
        stopPlayer();
        startMediaPlayer(url);

    }

    private void stopPlayer() {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
            sendPlayerStatus("stopped");

        }
    }

    public void startMediaPlayer(String url) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
            return;
        if (mPlayer == null)
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    if (extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED
                            || extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED) {
                        sendPlayerStatus("erroronplaying");
                    } else if (extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO) {
                        sendPlayerStatus("erroronplaying");
                        return false;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            mPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

                public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                    Log.e("onBufferingUpdate", "" + percent);

                }
            });
            mPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mPlayer.start();
                    sendPlayerStatus("playing");
                }
            });
            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Log.e("onCompletion", "Yes");
                    sendPlayerStatus("completed");
                }
            });
            mPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendPlayerStatus(String status) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY);
        intent.putExtra(PLAYER_STATUS_KEY, status);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

**player.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ab_tool"
        android:text="Home" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartMediaPlayer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
        android:text="Start Player" />


    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/togglePauseResume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnStartMediaPlayer"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textOff="Resume"
        android:textOn="Pause" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeTrack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/togglePauseResume"
        android:text="Chanage Track" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStopMediaPlayer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnChangeTrack"
        android:text="STOP" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".PlayerScreen">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<service android:name=".MediaPlayerService"></service>
```

To get data from streaming url header data you can [check this answer][2]

For testing purpose here i have used two urls

***UPDATE***
**PlayerActivity**

```
public class PlayerScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        startService(new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class));
        /*
        * To get url which is passing from the previous activity listitem click.
        * If url which is pass from listitem click is not empty it will start player
        * */
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url))
            startMediaPlayer(url);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiverFromservice, new IntentFilter(MediaPlayerService.SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY));
    }

    private String currentPlayerStatus = "N/A";
    private BroadcastReceiver receiverFromservice = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (MediaPlayerService.SERVICE_TO_ACTIVITY.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
                /*
                * To get current status of player
                * */
                currentPlayerStatus = intent.getStringExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_STATUS_KEY);
                Log.e("Player Mode", "" + currentPlayerStatus);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiverFromservice);
    }

    /**
     * TO start media player.It will send broadcast to Service & from service player will start
     *
     * @param url
     */
    public void startMediaPlayer(String url) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MediaPlayerService.BROADCAST_TO_SERVICE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_FUNCTION_TYPE, MediaPlayerService.PLAY_MEDIA_PLAYER);
        intent.putExtra(MediaPlayerService.PLAYER_TRACK_URL, url);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

let me know if anything.

Comment: thanks @user1140237 sir... I think this is fine But I need to check my radio Service Now Its down.. It will take 2 days to renew.... till that if possible Can you suggest me how to use [this in TabLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153697/android-changing-a-normal-layout-to-tab-layout-error-in-image-buttons-and-other)

Comment: @MLN you can test above code with any streaming url like from shoutcast [streaming url](http://91.121.164.210:8380/stream). URL which has mp3 or ogg codec.

Comment: thanks Is there any code sample at git-hub or something like that of your code... Here I tried missing some files ... Actually my code is making 30 sec delay so is there any code

Comment: @MLN nope theres not sample on git sorry... But what is missing let me know

Comment: I am getting Error at `isPlaying` cannot resolve.. and some other in `MediaPlayerService` so I am asking for any github or example etc.. for testing

Comment: @MLN reason for 30 seconds delay is might be not streaming url or its taking time to connection or might be buffering time

Comment: I need to justice both of you So Almost both u guys helped me So I have distributed them bounty and answer thanks for spending your effort and time on my question

Comment: Hope that you can solve my problem. This is similar to what I'm facing right now. Can you please look into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44447813/7004388) and guide me. I'm stuck there. Need help badly.

Comment: @user1140237 mine problem is similar one but my audio stream API has basic authentication hence I am using the public void setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri, Map<String, String> headers) I am getting the same exception as mentioned in the question, Playing works well little delayed but works, Can you tell me what may be the possible reason?

Answer (score 52):

Go to this file https://github.com/Old-Geek/Radio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/oucho/radio/Player.java#L234 and change

```
player.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(url));
```

to

```
player.setDataSource(url)
```

The problem is that `void setDataSource (String path)`  Sets the data source (file-path or http/rtsp URL) to use.

> path  String: the path of the file, or the http/rtsp URL of the stream you want to play

the github code uses `void setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri)` which assumes `uri` to be of some form of `ContentProvider`

> context   Context: the Context to use when resolving the Uri
>   uri Uri: the Content URI of the data you want to play

Comment: Thanks @Anurag Singh .. Now error Gone But I am getting This warning's `02-13 15:24:20.233 16769-16787/org.sss.text.liveradio D/MediaHTTPConnection: filterOutInternalHeaders: key=User-Agent, val= stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.1.1)
02-13 15:24:20.243 16769-16786/org.sss.text.liveradio D/MediaHTTPConnection: proxy null port 0
02-13 15:24:38.203 16769-16769/org.sss.text.liveradio E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
02-13 15:24:54.743 16769-16769/org.sss.text.liveradio E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
` and Its playing Same **30sec dilay**

Comment: Thanks Your answer worked.... But still its littlebit delay I will check and confirm bounty,,,,

Comment: I need to justice both of you So Almost both u guys helped me So I have distributed them bounty and answer thanks for spending your effort and time on my question

Answer (score 7):

On Android 9+ the clear net http trafic may cause this problem. Check this one: [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Answer (score 2):

This error also happens if this internet permission is not in the Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```